# Blogging on an HTML only site

Tags: php, html, css, ftp, blogs

I have tried searching for an answer, but i may be using the wrong phrases..

I am trying to create a stand alone blog for my girlfriend and i am a web designer, but she wants me to make an extremely personalized site. I therefore want to make her site out of HTML coding, with java or jquery scripting as well as CSS.

I don't want to use things like Wordpress or Joomla or blogger. Is there a way to allow her to blog on her site with only an HTML structure. Please bear in mind that she know nothing about HTML code and doesn't have any FTP software or inclination.

Basically she wants to log on and start typing like any other blog and she wants her own domain, but i only want to use HTML... or maybe a bit of PHP.

Can someone help?

Comment: You will definetly not be able to do it with just HTML. Is there a reason you don't want to use Joomla or Wordpress?

Comment: You can make custom themes with wordpress as well.

Comment: Since you know about front-end programming you could easily make your own Wordpress theme. Why don't you want that?

Comment: Can she learn Markdown? If that's the case, you could get a Markdown parser, plug it into a template, and have it search a directory for a file named `path.md`?

Comment: I hate wordpress or joomla, takes so long to edit and customise from the templates. creating an HTML site from scatch is WAY faster.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is Wordpress.

You can write your code only in HTML using Wordpress. You can also use PHP if you want to (using shortcodes). If a site is supposed to be completely static that is plain html, then login on cpanel and start writing your html code :) All you may need is a suitable template.

Comment: The think is I hate changing templates, i prefer to make my own site

Comment: you can stick with default template. Or may be you need a very simple template that is html like. Like it does not have those fancy widgets on the right menu. You can btw configure your wordpress like that (something that will be close). Or may be you can create your own very basic template. That should not be difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of PHP will solve your problem. Use TinyMCE or FCKEditor as WYSIWYG (what-you-see-is-what-you-get) editor in some sort of password protected area. Then you save the content of the editor in an HTML file (easy with PHP) and include the HTML file in the blog entry list (which is the page visitors will see). If you add MySQL you save the file writing and sorting (by date) of the blog, which could be tricky, if you use HTML files only.

Answer (score 1):

The use of PHP and a database would solve your problem. Type out a blog post, save it to a database (SQL or Access) and then retrieve it on a page that displays the blog posts.

Comment: It would also be extremely easy (for a web designer especially) to create pages to edit posts, upload attachments, and pictures etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a Content Management System, or CMS, and pretty much reinvent the wheel that Wordpress, Joomla, and Blogger already are.

You'll need some sort of server side language to accept input (whether it be images, blog posts, etc) to save them on the server, PHP can do this, [but it's still PHP](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html). Javascript cannot do that by itself, neither can HTML or CSS as I'm sure you know.

I highly recommend against rewriting the wheel like this for a few reasons. Primarily security. You could easily make a few mistakes in the log in page, subtle mistakes that don't even seem like mistakes that somebody could abuse to gain entry to the site's content. What good is a gorgeous site if you can't lock it down? The site would quickly lose integrity.

Maintaining a site like this can also be a problem for a single person such as yourself. The simplest CMS is the most rigid, but I imagine she'd want control over rigidity. If you're doing this yourself, this becomes difficult quickly. This will take a lot of time and effort. Time and effort you won't be paid for.

If you do undertake this, she's going to have requests and you will quickly turn into a business relationship when it comes to the site. She'll be your client, always making requests asking you for help when it doesn't do what she expects it to. This is stressful/annoying in work environments, I can't imagine what it'd do to a relationship.

Can this be done using purely HTML/Javascript/CSS? No.

Can this be done with a little PHP? Yes.

Should it? I recommend against it. Find a Wordpress-esque site that gives you the control she wants and go with it. It'll save you a lot of time, effort, and maybe even the relationship, you never know. If you still want to design the look of her site, many of these sites allow for that but still have the powerful, secure, and maintained-by-other-people backend that will make the site that much easier to blog for.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want something simple, you can use [Scriptogr.am](http://www.scriptogr.am) for instance. It stores your posts in Dropbox and is written in MarkDown language, which is an easier way to blog than HTML.

If you need some comments, you can check a comments platform such as [Disqus](http://disqus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple Ruby on Rails Application, like described here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
It would take you only 20 minutes to start it and you can deploy it directly to heroku to have the content hostet.